# How I can keep the sesion open to me and my users?

Tags: wordpress

On my website, the sessions unexpectedly close, and I have to log in again. I have already tried to fix it in WordPress, but the problem persists.

I also tried using a plugin, but I don't want to add just one plugin for that issue. I believe it can be resolved within WordPress. Could you please assist me?